# How to implement width_bucket function in a single query

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-pl

Oracle SQL provides

```
width_bucket(expression,min_value,max_value,num_buckets)
```

function to create a histogram. [WIDTH_BUCKET Oracle SQL Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions214.htm). I want to know if the same functionality can be achieved using a nested query or something ?

**Update:** If it is not possible through a single query, I would like to know which of the following methods to implement the histogram function would be fastest in performance?

1. SQL PL stored procedure
2. JAVA stored procedure
3. JDBC program

Comment: Do you mean in oracle, or in ansi sql, or what?

Comment: I don't care about oracle or ansi, just want to know the general query (if at all possible) that would be able to do the trick.

Comment: A "general" query usually means ansi SQL. In ANSI, you're not going to be able to get the needed virtual table (created in memory via some select or function) you'll need in order to join on. You're going to need a virtual table with rows for each bucket. That is unfortunately not easy at all in ANSI. In each specific flavor of SQL, you will have better options. Like in PostgreSQL, you have GENERATE_SEQUENCE, which will get you started. In Oracle, you have CONNECT BY.  But if you're using Oracle, why not just use WIDTH_BUCKET?

Answer (score 0):

WIDTH_BUCKET ( e, m, M, p ) is an ISO SQL function that can be convert in a simple mathematic formulae...

The strict equivalent in "plain" SQL is :

```
CASE 
   WHEN e < m 
      THEN 0
   ELSE 1 + FLOOR((e - m ) / ((M - m)/p))
END
```